# SAPui 5 Page as a popup window

Tags: sapui5

I want to crate a popup window with close button and the content of the popup will be a split-app master-detail page.Which control should we use to achieve this?

1. I've tried with a sap.m.page but unable to change height and width.
2. I've tried with a sap.m.ResponsivePopover but i can't remove the arrow thing on the top from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.I have used overlaycontainer to acheive the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow in sap.m.ResponsivePopover is using the css classes .sapMPopoverArrUp and .sapMPopoverArr so you could probably overwrite them locally to remove the arrow.